# Combining 2 tables with no dates in common

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to combine two tables that have no dates in common only a caseid.
Here is my SQL code. I am also trying to combine the EcoDate and ProductionMonth columns as they both contain date information.

```
SELECT     cmp.ProductionMonth, cmp.ProductionAmount, rce.EcoDate, rcl.CaseCaseId, cmp.CaseCaseId AS CaseId, rce.GrossOil  
FROM         PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_465 AS rcl INNER JOIN
                      PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_465 AS rce ON rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rce.ReportRunCaseId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      CaseMonthlyProduction AS cmp ON rcl.CaseCaseId = cmp.CaseCaseId
```

If I were to run this query as 2 different ones I would get an output like this:

```
CaseCaseId-----EcoDate----GrossOil
12345------------2013-1-1------125.3
12345------------2013-2-1------15.3
12345------------2013-3-1------12.3
12345------------2013-4-1------125.0
12345------------2013-5-1------15.0
12345------------2013-6-1------120.3
12346------------2013-1-1------422.2
12346------------2013-2-1------325.2
12346------------2013-3-1------100.0


CaseId--------ProductionMonth------ProductionAmount
12345------------2016-1-1-----------------223.0
12345------------2016-2-1-----------------254.1
12345------------2016-3-1-----------------652.1
12345------------2016-4-1-----------------255.9
12346------------2016-1-1-----------------111.1
12346------------2016-2-1-----------------621.2
```

My output table should be like this:

```
CaseCaseId-------Date--------GrossOil--------ProductionAmount
12345------------2013-1-1------125.3-----------------null
12345------------2013-2-1------15.3------------------null
12345------------2013-3-1------12.3------------------null
12345------------2013-4-1------125.0-----------------null
12345------------2013-5-1------15.0------------------null
12345------------2013-6-1------120.3-----------------null
12345------------2016-1-1-------null------------------223.0
12345------------2016-2-1-------null------------------254.1
12345------------2016-3-1-------null------------------652.1
12345------------2016-4-1-------null------------------255.9
12346------------2013-1-1------422.2-----------------null
12346------------2013-2-1------325.2-----------------null
12346------------2013-3-1------100.0-----------------null
12346------------2016-1-1-------null------------------111.1
12346------------2016-2-1-------null------------------621.2
```

When I use a right outer join, it returns all of the CaseIds in the database instead of just the ones that are part of PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_465. Also, I am not sure how to combine the two date fields into one. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
select * from (
select
 rc1.CaseId,
 rce.EcoDat as Date,
 rce.GrossOil,
 0 as ProductionAmount
from phdrpt.reportcaselist_465 as rcl
 inner join phdrpt.rptcaseeco_465 as rce
  on rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rce.ReportRunCaseId
union
 rc1.CaseId,
 cmp.ProductionMonth as Date,
 0 as GrossOil,
 cmp.ProductionAmount
from phdrpt.reportcaselist_465 as rcl
 inner join CaseMonthlyProduction AS cmp
  on rcl.CaseCaseId = cmp.CaseCaseId
) order by date
```

Comment: Thanks catfood. I am getting an error after the ). Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Comment: This made it work.  `select
 rcl.ReportRunCaseId,
 rce.EcoDate as Date,
 rce.GrossOil,
 0 as ProductionAmount
from phdrpt.reportcaselist_465 as rcl
 inner join phdrpt.rptcaseeco_465 as rce
  on rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rce.ReportRunCaseId
union
select
 rcl.ReportRunCaseId,
 cmp.ProductionMonth as Date,
 0 as GrossOil,
 cmp.ProductionAmount
from phdrpt.reportcaselist_465 as rcl
 inner join CaseMonthlyProduction AS cmp
  on rcl.ReportRunCaseId = cmp.CaseCaseId
  order by rcl.ReportRunCaseId, Date`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select CaseCaseId AS CaseCaseId, EcoDate AS Date, GrossOil AS GrossOil, NULL AS ProductionAmount FROM table1
union all
select CaseId AS CaseCaseId, ProductionMonth AS Date, NULL AS GrossOil, ProductionAmount AS ProductionAmount FROM table2
```

[Union operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can FULL OUTER JOIN, and then use ISNULL to get what you want.  Don't forget to join on the dates too.

```
SELECT     isnull(rcl.CaseCaseId,cmp.CaseCaseId) as CaseId,
           isnull(cmp.ProductionMonth,rce.EcoDate) as Date,
           rce.GrossOil, 
           cmp.ProductionAmount
FROM       PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_465 AS rcl 
INNER JOIN PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_465 AS rce 
ON rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rce.ReportRunCaseId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CaseMonthlyProduction AS cmp 
ON rcl.CaseCaseId = cmp.CaseCaseId
and rce.EcoDate = cmp.ProductionMonth
```

Comment: The isnull works great but when I do this I get all of the caseids in the database not just the ones that belong to reportcaselist_465

Comment: So you don't want a full outer join?  You only want rows from CaseMonthlyProduction if they have a matching row in ReportCaseList_465?  I have edited my answer for that.

Comment: This limits the output to the number of rows of the second query only. I believe that union is the way to go.